Lock in new form state after submitting so that a subsequent form reset does not revert to values prior to saving
I have a simple form in a modal. Saving the form does not reload the page. Instead I simply close the modal and update the text on the page to reflect the changes made in the form.
When the user closes the modal without saving the form, I want to reset any changes they made to the form. Note the close buttons have the type "reset":
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <form id='myForm' onsubmit='return false;' action='someTarget'>
      <div class="modal-header mb-3">
        <h5 class="modal-title">My Modal</h5>
        <button class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" type="reset" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div><!-- end .modal-header -->
      <div class="modal-body mt-3">
        <div class="row">
          <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Name</label>
          <div class="col-8 col-form-label"><input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" /></div>
          <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end mt-4">
            <button class="btn btn-label-secondary me-sm-3 me-1" data-bs-dismiss="modal" type="reset" aria-label="Close">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-animated-submit" type="submit"><span class="tf-icon bx bx-trash bx-s me-2"></span> Save</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- end .row -->
      </div><!-- end .modal-body -->
     </form>
    </div><!-- end .modal-content -->
  </div><!-- end .modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- end .modal#exampleModal -->

However, if the user makes changes to the form and saves it, only to open and close it again later - thus resetting the form - the form reverts to its original state prior to saving.
How I can change the form's "default" state when saving so that when the reset event is triggered, it reverts to the values of the last submitted state - not the one from when the page first loaded?

I found the solution to my problem. Upon saving the form, I was able to set a property called defaultValue. Resetting the form subsequently sets the value to the new defaultValue
I did this with jQuery
form.find('*').filter(':input').each(function(){         $(this).prop( 'defaultValue', $(this).val() );       });
